# AWS Kinesis, concurrent Lambda processing with a guaranteed ordering

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a Lambda with an Event source pointed to a Kinesis Stream Consumer (with an arbitrary number of shards)

I would like to ensure that items in the stream with the same 'partition key' are processed by Lambda in sequence and not simultaneously. ( This is being used as the object's identity, and I don't want multiple Lambdas performing logic on the same object simultaneously.)

For example, if the items in the stream have partition keys:

1,2,1,3,4,1,2,1

If we take the order of processing to be left to right, Lambda would process an item with each of the partition keys 1,2, 3 and 4 concurrently. Then, when it has finished an item with a specific partition key it can start processing another one with that key.

Is this achievable in some way, without the use of a distributed lock that would make inefficient use of Lambda?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I was tackling the problem in the wrong way. Lambda guarantees that within a shard, the Lambda instance is invoked on one batch at a time. Therefore, there is no need for a distributed lock as at worst there will be multiple records belonging to the same entity in the same batch and processing them in order can be managed in-memory within the Lambda function itself.

Reference from the AWS FAQs http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

> Q: How does AWS Lambda process data from Amazon Kinesis streams and
> Amazon DynamoDB Streams?
>
> The Amazon Kinesis and DynamoDB Streams records sent to your AWS
> Lambda function are strictly serialized, per shard. **This means that if
> you put two records in the same shard, Lambda guarantees that your
> Lambda function will be successfully invoked with the first record
> before it is invoked with the second record**. If the invocation for one
> record times out, is throttled, or encounters any other error, Lambda
> will retry until it succeeds (or the record reaches its 24-hour
> expiration) before moving on to the next record. The ordering of
> records across different shards is not guaranteed, and processing of
> each shard happens in parallel.

Comment: You are absolutely right, pay attention that in some cases and configuration you may lose order, make sure the configuration is correct - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-failure-handling-features-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources

Answer (score 5):

Items with the same 'partition key' will be processed by Lambda in sequence for stream event source mapping.

Moreover, you can specify 'concurrent batches per shard' when creating Lambda trigger:

1. If 'concurrent batches per shard' is 1 (default one), then the order will be preserved for the whole shard.
2. If 'concurrent batches per shard' is [2;10], then the order will be preserved only for records with the same partition key within the shard.

You can check about concurrent batches ([ParallelizationFactor](http://%20%20https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-parallelization-factor-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/)) in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html